# User is not stored in the database Spring

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-security

I write application on Spring with security. I made database with users and I can Login in app as user from database. But when I try to register new user in DB it don't stored.

> I have no errors, just redirect to main page.

If I uncomment autologin string I get Null Point EX.

Here is structure of my app:

[image]

UserServiceImpl.class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service; 
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import com.ya.pokupay.dao.RoleDAO;
import com.ya.pokupay.dao.UserDAO;
import com.ya.pokupay.model.Role;
import com.ya.pokupay.model.User;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDAO roleDao;

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        System.out.println("HERE");
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(roleDao.getOne(1L));
        user.setRoles(roles);
        System.out.println("user: " + user);
        userDao.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userDao.findByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.save(userForm);

        //securityService.autoLogin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getConfirmPassword());

        return "redirect:/all";
    }
```

UserDetailServiceImpl:

```
import com.ya.pokupay.dao.UserDAO;
import com.ya.pokupay.model.Role;
import com.ya.pokupay.model.User;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {        
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

If it can help I can add some more code or settings.

EDITED:

UserDAO:

```
import com.ya.pokupay.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything transaction related in your service. Without transactions not much is going to get persisted.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I added UserDAO in question. There is realization of save method from JPA.

Comment: @Dmitry  are you sure  userService.save(userForm); line is hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find solution, so I just wrote my own implementation of asve method and it works for me.